# Docker doesn't mount dirs from host's /tmp properly on my ubuntu20 VM

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On my ubuntu 20 VM (hyper-V on win11 host), I want to run a docker container and mount a directory from the host path `/tmp/x` (src dir) into the docker container. I use the following command:

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/x:/home/a 5472ef85a106 bash --verbose
```

In the container I can see the destination dir `/home/a` but it does not contain anything even though the src-dir on the host has content. When I create a file in there, it does not appear in the src folder on the host, but when I mount another container with the same command, I can find the file in its destination dir (`/home/a`) again, so it seems like docker uses a different src dir somehow. Can someone explain this behavior to me or give directions how to debugging?

I tried mounting another dir, which works perfectly fine (e.g. from src `/home/something`). When I run `docker inspect` on the container, the output for both mounts (the working and the bad one) looks the same:

```
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/tmp/x",
                "Destination": "/home/asdf",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/peter/tmp/archive",
                "Destination": "/home/works",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

/tmp is not a mount itself on the host and I tried different mount options in the docker call.